# nodemon says" [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..." after i hit post request

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, nodemon

I am trying to `insert` some data through post request to `Mongo` but after sending post request `Nodemon` says [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...",

But the data will get inserted to `MongoDB` even after crashing.

```
    router.post('/insert', (req, res) => {
    var res = new Researcher({
        name: req.body.name,
        position: req.body.position,
        intrest: req.body.intrest,

    });
    res.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err) { res.send(doc); }
        else { console.log('Error in Researcher Save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});
```

Comment: The code you are posting is `POST` and you hit `PUT` request?

Comment: Yea sorry after post request?

Comment: remove comma in `intrest`

Comment: no still the same

Comment: Even after ending the task it is the same , and it only for post request i am getting correct output for get request

Comment: and for post request the values are getting inserted but after i hit post nodemon says app crashed

Comment: Once reinstall all `dependencies` and try again `npm install`

Comment: yea it helped it started working thankyou